# Body of response with statuscode 401

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home, api-ai

I'm trying to enable some kind of "voice unlinking" (which should remove the access token from the google assistant) for my google action. I'm using the webhook fulfillment via Dialogflow and I'd like to send a response text like "**Okay, your account linking got removed.**"

To do so, I'm currently trying to send a response using the status code 401, but it seems that my response body gets either ignored by the assistant or filtered along the way.

So my question is:

Is there a way to add any body information to a response with status code 401 or are there other ways to achieve the removing of access tokens via response?

Comment: Having the same problem for more than a year now. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393868/force-user-to-relink-his-her-account, too.

Comment: It sounds like you may be trying to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125906/how-to-revoke-access-token-from-google-assistant

Comment: Thanks for your response. The solution of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125906/how-to-revoke-access-token-from-google-assistant is what I'm actually doing right now. I'm looking for a way to add any "readable output" for the assistant to that 401-response.